# Control-F2 "Move Focus to Menu Bar" only works occasionally

Tags: macos, keyboard, ui

I don't want to use my trackpad too much due to a strain injury, hence I use the Control F2 "Move Focus to Menu Bar" a lot.

However this feature only works occasionally, it can work for hours and then suddenly stop working, sometimes I can fix in the Keyboard Shortcuts pref pane by unchecking and checking the "Move Focus to Menu Bar" checkbox, at other times it takes a restart of the system.

[image]

I'm a big Apple fan-boy, and I always marvel at the cool features in OSX, this is the first time I have a Windows-esque experience with the OSX UI :(

Comment: This is a 10 year old question and sitting here in 2021 (almost 2022) it's still an issue in Monterey. SMH

Comment: This is an 11-year-old question and sitting here in 2023 it's still an issue in Ventura. SMH

Comment: This is a 12 year old question and sitting here in 2024 it's still an issue in Sonoma.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you're sure you've got your Fn key settings the way you want them and it STILL doesn't work:

My solution:

1. Go back into Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts pane.
2. For the item "Move focus to the menu bar",
   assign a DIFFERENT function key, other than F2.
   (Something you're not using, like, say...^F9...or whatever.)
3. Now use THAT key instead.

Sounds kind of nuts, I know.  And it's annoying to use a different key.  But I've found that ^F2 just won't consistently work after I've been using enough 3rd party programs, particularly if they're complex.  Sometimes ^F3 will also fail, and that keyboard pane can start acting a little strange on its own to be honest.  This does seem to work though.

---

coder

Comment: That seems to work! You're lifesaver, thx a bunch :)

Comment: Well, some time have past and I have the exactly same problem with this approach :(

Comment: My experience: after if fails with the "new" key mapping, switch it back to the original one, and it typically starts working again. Then I toggle between these two mappings to make it work when one (mapping) starts failing. Which is unfortunately often.

Comment: What an absolute disaster! I'm still seeing this issue on Yosemite.

Comment: I noticed "Move focus to the menu bar" got turned off for some reason after upgrading from El Capitan (10.11) to Sierra (10.12)

Comment: This approach is hit and miss. Frustrating when the latter occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it annoyed me so much. I thought i messed up the keybinding.

Comment: I still cannot understand what is "magic" about ^F2 but I won't look a gifted horse in its mouth. Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 18):

- I've had the same struggle with keyboard shortcuts to the menu bar (tried many different combinations).

the only one that has consistently worked is the help shortcut ⇧ ⌘ ? (shift+command+/)

from the help menu just use the arrows to navigate to file/edit/view…

Comment: This works, plus you can just type the command you want to find immediately.

Answer (score 17):

Same here: ^F2 almost never works
Workaround that works for me (without assigning new shortcut):
press ^F3 and then immediately ^F2

Comment: I've solved this problem by mapping a keycombo with Keyboard Maestro to simulate pressing the Apple icon in the upper left corner of the screen.

Comment: This crazy seeming way does work - even for remapped shortcut (I use ^; instead of ^F2) . Any idea why?

Comment: Yep, seconding the "why?" because it does work.

Answer (score 1):

From this other question:
[Why do Ctrl+F2 and Ctrl+F3 sometimes stop working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103956/why-do-ctrlf2-and-ctrlf3-sometimes-stop-working)

A possible cause is accidentally hitting Ctrl-F1, which (wait for it...) disables Keyboard access! So use it again to toggle these keys back on.

Comment: I'm trying this shortcut for the first time on macOS Ventura, and if you go into Sys Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard, you can see clearly that Ctrl-F1 checks/unchecks a bunch of the shortcuts. Except even when they are checked, "Move focus to the menu bar" (Ctrl-F2) does nothing.

Comment: Hey, so you’re saying that Ctrl-F1 ia definitely not the cause of the problem, at least in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question in the following link and got a hint to answer your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390279/applescript-to-show-apple-menu-bar-items

What I do is as follows:

1. create an .app using Automator using the scrip in the above link,
2. create a hot key for the .app,
3. create a key stroke linked to the hot key (using KeyRemap4MacBook in my case).

It works great for me at least.

Comment: Or see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for other ways to assign shortcuts to scripts. Automator applications have a maybe 100-500 ms delay at the start.