# Global Fn ctrl F2?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

From the Finder Fn+ctrl+F2 select the Apple Menu icon. Is there a way to make this keyboard kung fu global so that I can use it from within all the apps to get to the Apple icon in the menu bar?

[image]

-------EDIT

Per timothymh's comment, these are the apps in my menu bar:
[image]

- ScreenHero      <--- Launching this seems to be the culprit?
- Postgres.app
- BlueTooth
- GoogleDrive
- Wireless
- AppleTV
- Keyboard Input
- Battery
- Spotlight
- Date/Time
- Siri
- Notifications

Comment: It should be global unless ctrl-F2 is a shortcut in the app you're using. When does it *not* work?

Comment: @timothymh that's what I thought - seems to only work from the Finder

Comment: Do you have anything installed that might be capturing your hotkey? Most often this would be a menu bar application of some sort, are you running any of those?

Comment: If something else is stealing it, ctrl/shift/F2 [+Fn depending on how your f-keys are set] should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104003/216401) I might also be hitting Fn+ctrl+F1
[image: System Preferences > Keyboard :: Shortcuts]
I'll try turning off keyboard access... toggling Fn+ctrl+F1 deselects the Fn+ctrl+F2 option. Ta da!