# "Move focus to the menubar" shortcut is not working on Sonoma?

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar

I have tried several different keyboard combos for this feature [which worked on prior versions of `macOS`] - but none work on `sonoma`

Here is one of the attempted combinations:  <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>.   I also had tried <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> - also to no avail.

[image]

Apps that I have tried to work with this (and none work): chrome, Pycharm, Finder, Preview, Messages.

Note: there is a very old similar question on this [Control-F2 "Move Focus to Menu Bar" only works occasionally](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12723/control-f2-move-focus-to-menu-bar-only-works-occasionally)- and I had already tried their solution by using different keyboard combinations.